# Running Container Registry in Gitlab with relative url

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, registry

I'm running gitlab and nginx in docker. I had to use an unbound version of nginx because there's other applications running and I can only publish ports 80 and 443. So far I've managed to access gitlab with `my.domain.com/gitlab/` and can also login, upload projects, etc...

I've wanted to use the container registry for uploading and storing images from my projects, which is why I've uncommented `gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true` in `gitlab.rb`. Now the container registry is visible for my projects, however I get a `Docker Connection Error` when trying to access the page.

My question is, are there any other settings I have to tweak to get the inbuilt container registry running or did I already mess things up in the way I've set this up? Especially since I need gitlab to run on a relative url and my projects url for cloning/pulling is something like `https://<server.ip.address>/gitlab/group-name/test-project`, even though browser tabs show `https://my.domain.com/gitlab/group-name/test-project`

So far, this is my setup:

nginx

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name my.domain.com www.my.domain.com;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;

##############
##  GITLAB  ##
##############
  location /gitlab/ {
    root /home/git/gitlab/public;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_pass http://<server.ip.address>:8929/gitlab/;

    gzip                    off;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}
```

gitlab docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  git:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.10.0-ce.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: 'my.domain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
         external_url 'http://<server.ip.address>:8929/gitlab/'
         gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
    ports:
      - "8929:8929"
      - "2224:2224"
```

Comment: did you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: yes, I just added the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, so for anyone else looking this is what I adjusted to get things running

```yaml
# gitlab.rb
registry_external_url 'my.domain.com' # do not add the relative url e.g. /gitlab
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050 # make sure you can access this port e.g. in docker add '- "5050:5050" '
# add the certs from the base url
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/certs/registry/domain.pem" 
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/certs/registry/domain_key.pem"
```

The command `docker login my-domain.com/gitlab` will always remove any kind of relative urls and try to access `my-domain.com/v2/`, so add this to the proxy config

```bash
###########################
## DOCKER IMAGE REGISTRY ##
###########################
  location /v2/ {

   client_max_body_size 0;
   proxy_set_header    Host $host;
   proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_pass          https://<server-ip>:5050; # 5050 needs to be the port you defined in gitlab.rb OR the forwarded port from docker
  }
```

I also adjusted the nginx gitlab configuration:

```bash
 location /gitlab {
 <...>
   proxy_pass http://<server-ip>:8929;
```

Hope this helps anyone else.